# Spark executor sends result to a random port though all the ports are explicitly set up

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run a spark job with PySpark through Jupyter notebook running in Docker. Workers are located on separate machines in the same network. I am performing a `take` operation on RDD:

```py
data.take(number_of_elements)
```

When the `number_of_elements` is 2000 everything works fine. When it is 20000 an exception occurs. From my point of view it breaks when the size of the result exceeds 2GB (or it seems for me so). The idea about 2GB comes from that spark can send results smaller than 2GB in one block and when the result is bigger than 2GB another mechanism starts to work and something breaks there ([see here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a950570f91db56cbae488c82def49cd0da16e996/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/io/ChunkedByteBufferFileRegion.scala#L25)). Here is the exception from executor log:

```
19/11/05 10:27:14 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 205.7623 ms
19/11/05 10:27:40 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 25421, boot = 3, init = 1751, finish = 23667
19/11/05 10:27:42 INFO MemoryStore: Block taskresult_4 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 927.7 MB, free 6.4 GB)
19/11/05 10:27:42 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 4). 972788748 bytes result sent via BlockManager)
19/11/05 10:27:49 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result ChunkFetchSuccess{streamChunkId=StreamChunkId{streamId=1585998572000, chunkIndex=0}, buffer=org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerManagedBuffer@4399ad49} to /10.0.0.9:56222; closing connection
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferFileRegion.transferTo(ChunkedByteBufferFileRegion.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageWithHeader.transferTo(MessageWithHeader.java:121)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWriteFileRegion(NioSocketChannel.java:355)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1321)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:983)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.flush(AbstractChannel.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$1.run(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:284)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As we can see from the log executor tries to send result to `10.0.0.9:56222`. It fails because the port is not opened in docker compose. `10.0.0.9` is an IP address of a master node but port `56222` is random though I explicitly set up all ports I can find in [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) to disable random port selection:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder\
.master('spark://spark.cyber.com:7077')\
.appName('My App')\
.config('spark.task.maxFailures', '16')\
.config('spark.driver.port', '20002')\
.config('spark.driver.host', 'spark.cyber.com')\
.config('spark.driver.bindAddress', '0.0.0.0')\
.config('spark.blockManager.port', '6060')\
.config('spark.driver.blockManager.port', '6060')\
.config('spark.shuffle.service.port', '7070')\
.config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '14g')\
.getOrCreate()
```

I mapped these ports with docker compose:

```py
version: "3"
services:
  jupyter:
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest
    ports:
      - "4040-4050:4040-4050"
      - "6060:6060"
      - "7070:7070"
      - "8888:8888"
      - "20000-20010:20000-20010"
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory of your Docker container to 4Go for example ?

Comment: It's 14GB. I think, that the problem is not with memory, but with ChunkedByteBufferFileRegion: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a950570f91db56cbae488c82def49cd0da16e996/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/io/ChunkedByteBufferFileRegion.scala#L25 @ML_TN

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion helped me eventually. You are welcome to post the answer and I'll accept it @ML_TN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably configure you spark driver memory to follow your docker container memory settings

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
.config('spark.driver.memory', '14g')
```

as @ML_TN proposed and everything works now.

From my point of view it is strange that the memory setting affects the ports that spark uses.